# Need a python module for numerical and scientific computing other than NumPy and SciPy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, rounding, precision

Simple operations, such as rounding a number, creating an increasing vector, etc., can't be done reliably in python (see the examples below). The common explanation given by the python community is the floating point precision.

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Sep 29 2016, 13:33:00) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.round(2.5)
2.0
>>> numpy.round(3.5)
4.0
>>> numpy.arange(89,90,0.1)
array([ 89. ,  89.1,  89.2,  89.3,  89.4,  89.5,  89.6,  89.7,  89.8,  89.9])
>>> numpy.arange(89+0.1,90,0.1)
array([ 89.1,  89.2,  89.3,  89.4,  89.5,  89.6,  89.7,  89.8,  89.9,  90. ])
>>> numpy.arange(19,20,0.1)
array([ 19. ,  19.1,  19.2,  19.3,  19.4,  19.5,  19.6,  19.7,  19.8,  19.9])
>>> numpy.arange(19+0.1,20,0.1)
array([ 19.1,  19.2,  19.3,  19.4,  19.5,  19.6,  19.7,  19.8,  19.9])
>>>
```

However, there are existing tools, like Matlab and Octave, that do not suffer from such floating point precision phenomena (see the examples below). These tools also work on the binary architectures as python and are still capable of doing the real schoolbook math.

```
>> round(2.5)
ans =  3
>> round(3.5)
ans =  4
>> [89:0.1:90]
ans =

   89.000   89.100   89.200   89.300   89.400   89.500   89.600   89.700   89.800   89.900   90.000

>> [89+0.1:0.1:90]
ans =

   89.100   89.200   89.300   89.400   89.500   89.600   89.700   89.800   89.900   90.000

>> [19:0.1:20]
ans =

   19.000   19.100   19.200   19.300   19.400   19.500   19.600   19.700   19.800   19.900   20.000

>> [19+0.1:0.1:20]
ans =

   19.100   19.200   19.300   19.400   19.500   19.600   19.700   19.800   19.900   20.000

>>
```

I have already written my own `round` operation for python. I'm about to write my own `range` operation for python, and who knows what else in the future...

My question is following:
**Before I write the whole new math module for python, is there maybe such a module already existing?**
(and I mean a module that is capable of doing the real trustworthy schoolbook math)

Comment: If you want rational arithmetic then see the fractions library.

Comment: There's also a decimal library which looks like what you want but I've never used it.

Comment: Yeah, the decimal library offers fast arbitrary precision.

Comment: You should definitely take a look at the standard decimal module, but it just does basic arithmetic (including square roots). If you want a library that can do advanced mathematical functions at arbitrary precision, take a look at [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org)

Comment: what exactly is the issue with the vectors generated by the `numpy.arange` examples?

Comment: He doesn't like its handling of the endpoints.  `linspace` is the recommended alternative.

Comment: Regarding rounding, you say "The common explanation given by the python community is the floating point precision."  That's not the explanation for numpy's rounding behavior.  As the [docstring for `numpy.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) (equivalent to `numpy.round`) explains, "For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, Numpy
rounds to the nearest even value."

Comment: Given the comments and answers I've read, it seems like the user assumed a different library and even language to act the same way... But the assumption did not hold up. In addition, rather than read the documentation for numpy round and numpy arange he declares them broken... When the reality is that their behavior does not match his assumed behavior.

Comment: Something this wrong can't make it to masses. There might be bugs but this much of wrongness means you are misinterpreting what you see.

Comment: Wow, what reactions... I have made so many people angry today. Either this is a very sensitive topic or I'm living in some kind of parallel universe. Well in my universe, 2.5 rounded to the nearest integer equals 3.

Comment: What is the point of asking a program to round a number if its going to mess it up?

Comment: "what exactly is the issue with the vectors generated by the numpy.arange examples? – Stelios" To be clear, I have no problem with excluding the last value in a range, but let it be consistent...

Comment: @BorisL.  Your problem is you assume "different from what I am used to" is the same as "wrong".  I have seen nearly an entire class fail a homework assignment because MATLAB's rounding behavior changed their random distributions.  Numpy wouldn't have had this problem because it chose a statistically superior rounding rule.

Comment: @borisl everything you have written here drips with hubris

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing unreliable about numpy's behavior in the examples you show as compared to MATLAB, nor do any of the examples you show have anything to do with floating-point issues (with one exception).

For the rounding behavior, MATLAB is the one doing it wrong here. Numpy is following the [IEEE standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Rounding_floating-point_numbers) for rounding.  The standard calls for rounding to the nearest even number when the decimal value is `.5`.  There is a good reason for this: MATLAB's rounding behavior is statistically biased, producing more higher values than lower values for random numbers.

For the `arange` function, Numpy is following the [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) convention, which excludes the last value in a range, while MATLAB is following the closed interval convention, which includes the last value.  Neither is right or wrong, and both have their advantages and disadvantages, but Numpy's behavior is in line with the vast majority of programming languages.

If you want to use closed intervals, you can use the `linspace` function, which lets you control whether to include the last value or not (it includes the last value by default).  If you really need to use the range function, it is easy to add one value on to the end, or create your own wrapper function that does it automatically.

As for floating-point issues, MATLAB and numpy are exactly the same.  Both use identical [IEEE-standard floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (except where MATLAB violates the standard's rounding rules).  Python, however, supports true [decimal numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html), which MATLAB doesn't, so it is at least possible to avoid these issues in Python but not in MATLAB.

The only exception is this operation: `numpy.arange(89+0.1,90,0.1)`.  The result you show is indeed a floating-point issue.  As I said, floating-point issues like these present in both MATLAB and numpy.  This particular example was present in numpy but not MATLAB, but there are other examples that show up in MATLAB but not numpy.

For ranges, numpy does the arithmetic very literally in this case: it adds the step size to the starting value, then adds it again to that value, and so on.  This means that these issues happen in a very predictable way.  MATLAB apparently tries to be more clever, but that means it fails in more obscure and hard-to-predict ways (I can't find documentation on exactly how MATLAB does this calculation).  For both MATLAB and numpy, you really should be using `linspace` for these sorts of ranges, as it doesn't have these sorts of issues.

Comment: Fair enough,`linspace` might be a better option, but I don't like it because it requires calculation of the number of steps, when one targets a specific step size. Anyway, I'll give it a try...

Comment: Regarding the rounding, maybe it's time to revise the IEEE standard for rounding. After all, science of mathematics exists much longer than the computers and the rules for rounding were defined before the IEEE standard existed.

Comment: There are lots of rules for rounding out there, not just one. IEEE implements most of them via its selectable rounding modes. The one rule that you are looking for is the one taught to school children. The one that IEEE and numpy default to is the one preferred by scientists, engineers, and statisticians.

Comment: @BorisL. As I explained, there is a good reason for those rules.  It is considered a better approach overall because it is statistically unbiased.  Generally people dealing with random numbers don't want their `round` function changing the distribution of your numbers.  The rounding rule, which long predates the IEEE, is used because it avoids that problem.  See, for example, the wikipedia article on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up

Comment: @BorisL. You can either calculate the number of steps or you can deal with the floating-point issues.  This is going to be the case on both numpy and MATLAB.  At least for numpy `linspace` keeps the endpoints and number of steps consistent, while `arange` (as best as possible) keeps the step size consistent.  In MATLAB, `linspace` keeps the endpoint and number of steps consistent, while ranges can do one or the other based on apparently undocumented rules.

Comment: "The standard calls for rounding to the nearest even number when the decimal value is .5." <- This is a bit of a stretch. The standard specifies rounding rules that are used to determine the final bit(s) of a significand in the case of a tie in the result of a floating-point operation. But that's not the same thing as specifying the behaviour for rounding a float to an integer. For that, IEEE 754-2008 specifies five separate functions (`roundToIntegralTiesToEven`, `roundToIntegralTiesToAway`, ...) and doesn't give any indication that any of these functions is preferred over the others.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that the choice of ties-to-even is a reasonable one, but it's hard to infer that choice directly from the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: section 4.3.3 of the current revision of the standard says "The roundTiesToEven rounding-direction attribute shall be the default rounding-direction attribute for results in binary formats."  So yes, it does say which function is preferred.

Comment: @TheBlackCat: Yes, it says what's preferred for rounding the result of arithmetic operations to the nearest representable value! That's *not* the same thing as being the preferred rounding mode for rounding a float to an integer. It's reasonable to guess that the IEEE 754 folks *might* have recommended round-ties-to-even as the preferred choice for the latter operation, but it would still be a guess: that preference is *not* encoded in the standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129246/discussion-between-theblackcat-and-mark-dickinson).

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of libraries out there:

- SAML (Simple Algebraic Math Library)
- pymat
- PYML